# Payments REST API: Large amount causes "instrument declined" error in sandbox

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a Payflow Pro sandbox account.  I am submitting credit card transactions to the sandbox using Payments REST API.  I have found that if the amount is $1500 or greater, then the transaction fails with error: INSTRUMENT_DECLINED The instrument presented  was either declined by the processor or bank, or it can't be used for this payment.

However, the same fake credit card number works fine if the amount is less than $1500.

Is there a limit that I can adjust somewhere?  I've done some searching but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

I tried hitting the REST End point v1/payments/payment with the credit card 4556849459635348 (generated via [http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com](http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/)) and $1500 in one instance and $100 in another instance as the amount. Both of them went through.

Can you give me the fake card number so that I can try it my side and see if I can simulate the same error?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to test it.  I'm using Visa 4104833454433328 .  I'll try yours.  BTW I'm using CVV = 111, exp date 01/2020

Comment: I got a note from PayPal Merchant Technical Support stating that "test credit cards are set to auto decline any payment above $1500. For testing purposes you will need to use amounts less than $1500."